# replace all words with a certain symbol with another in a string

Tags: python-3.6

Hi guys do anyone know what's wrong with my code?
I am supposed to access a csv file and print in its format but when I attempt to print it, each values are split by commas and for the new line there is a `\n` connected with the first value of the next line. As such I attempted to replace all the commas with space to print it like a table but is confused on how to fix the `\n` from being connected to the first value of the new line.

```
filepath="C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\data\\"
filename="file.csv"

    with open(filepath+filename) as f:
        a=repr(f.read())
        b=a.replace(",", "     ")
        c=b.replace("\n", "  \n")


        print(c)
```

I am aware that my c does not work and is currently trying to find a way to separate all values with the `\n` connected to it.
Can you tell me what's wrong with my code and help me fix it please?
Thank you very much .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print every line after splitting it by comma and suppress the newline of `print()` with `end=''`:

```
with open(filepath+filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        print(*line.split(','), end='')
```

#### Example

This file content:

```
1,2
3,4
5,6
```

Produces this output:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

Use the optional keyword argument `sep` for more space between columns:

```
print(*line.split(','), end='', sep='   ')
```

Result:

```
1   2
3   4
5   6
```